# if input in list, select next item

Tags: python, list, input, cycle

For instance, this is the list:

```
exchange_list = ['coin', 'quarter', 'dime', 'penny', 'buck', 'bitcoin']

exchanger = input("Please give the input of a money currency that you'd like to exchange")
```

How do I make it so that if my input for instance is 'penny' that it selects the next item in the list (in this case 'buck'), and if the input is the same as the last item in the list (in this case 'bitcoin'), that it selects the first (in this case 'coin') ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, `in` and `index` might be useful here

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
index = (exchange_list.index(exchanger) + 1) % len(exchange_list)

print(exchange_list[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exchange_list = ['coin', 'quarter', 'dime', 'penny', 'buck', 'bitcoin']

exchanger = str(input("Please give the input of a money currency that you'd like to exchange: "))
foo = exchange_list.index(exchanger)
if foo == len(exchange_list)-1:
    print(exchange_list[0])
else:
     print(exchange_list[foo+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exchange_list = ['coin', 'quarter', 'dime', 'penny', 'buck', 'bitcoin']

exchanger = input("Please give the input of a money currency that you'd like to exchange")

location = exchange_list.index(exchanger)
currency = exchange_list[(location+1)%len(exchange_list)]

print(currency)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
exchange_list = ['coin', 'quarter', 'dime', 'penny', 'buck', 'bitcoin']

exchanger = input("Please give the input of a money currency that you'd like to exchange")

count=0
for item in exchange_list:
    if item==exchanger:   
        if count==len(exchange_list)-1:
            count=-1
        print(exchange_list[count+1]) # You can do other things too
    count=count+1
```